# How to use if-else condition in return Json to table use trHtML +=

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, jquery-mobile

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/section/search_go",
    data: { query: search_string },
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {
        console.log("Got " + response.length + " results");
        if (response.length === 0) {
            $("#customers").html(no_results_str);
        } else {
            var trHTML = "";
            $.each(response, function(i, item) {
                trHTML += "<tr>";
                trHTML += "<td>" + item.accountnumber + "</td>";
                trHTML += "<td>" + item.company + "</td>";
                trHTML += "<td>" + item.phone + "</td>";
                trHTML += "<td>" + item.postcode + "</td>";

                /// want to use
                      if (item.status = 1) {
                          echo "Complete";
                      }else{
                          echo "Non Complete";
                      }
                */////////////////////////////////

                trHTML += "</tr>";
            });
            $("#customers").html(trHTML);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `if (item.status = 1) {` should be `if (item.status == 1) {` = means, assignment and == equal means comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You are using variable response, but it can be undefined as length attribute.

[image: screenshot]

Try just

```
if(! response typeof undefined)
```

instead of

```
if(response.length === 0)
```